# How to Speed Up this Encryption Method C# Filestream

Tags: c#, encryption, filestream

I have encryption method that runs incredible slowly.   It takes around 20 minutes to encrypt several hundred MB of data.  I'm not sure if I'm taking the right approach.  Any help, thoughts, advice would be greatly appreciated.

```
    private void AES_Encrypt(string inputFile, string outputFile, byte[] passwordBytes, byte[] saltBytes)
    { 
        FileStream fsCrypt = new FileStream(outputFile, FileMode.Create);

        RijndaelManaged AES = new RijndaelManaged();

        AES.KeySize = 256;
        AES.BlockSize = 128;


        var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
        AES.Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8);
        AES.IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8);
        AES.Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros;

        AES.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;

        CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(fsCrypt,
             AES.CreateEncryptor(),
            CryptoStreamMode.Write);

        FileStream fsIn = new FileStream(inputFile, FileMode.Open);

        int data;
        while ((data = fsIn.ReadByte()) != -1)
            cs.WriteByte((byte)data);

        fsCrypt.Flush();
        cs.Flush();
        fsIn.Flush();

        fsIn.Close();
        cs.Close();
        fsCrypt.Close();
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: If I were to guess, reading and writing a byte at a time is probably slowing you down. Might want to try to `ReadAllBytes` from the `FileStream` and then `Write` the resulting buffer to the `CryptoStream`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While encryption can be slow, I wouldn't expect that to be the issue here. I suspect it's the byte-by-byte IO that's causing unnecessary overhead. The simplest way to fix that is with a judicious call to `Stream.CopyTo` - and while you're at it, you should use `using` statements to clean up appropriately:

```
private void AesEncrypt(string inputFile, string outputFile, byte[] passwordBytes, byte[] saltBytes)
{ 
    var key = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passwordBytes, saltBytes, 1000);
    RijndaelManaged aes = new RijndaelManaged
    {
        KeySize = 256,
        BlockSize = 128,
        Key = key.GetBytes(AES.KeySize / 8),
        IV = key.GetBytes(AES.BlockSize / 8),
        Padding = PaddingMode.Zeros,
        Mode = CipherMode.CBC
    };

    using (var output = File.Create(outputFile))
    {
        using (var crypto = new CryptoStream(output, aes.CreateEncryptor(), CryptoStreamMode.Write))
        {
            using (var input = File.OpenRead(inputFile))
            {
                input.CopyTo(crypto);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As noted on other answers, this isn't a good way of generating an IV. In general I'd prefer to use `Rijndael.Create()` instead of specifying `RijndaelManaged` - and you'd probably want to use a `using` statement for that, too.

Comment: Thank you!  You are awesome!  I will give this a go!

Comment: Right on!  Took 20% off my time!  Thanks so much :)

Comment: @Missy: That's not as much of an improvement as I'd expect, to be honest. Have you tried using Rijndael.Create instead of definitely using RijndaelManaged?

Comment: I don't know how to use Rigindael create and I'm under a crushing deadline.  I'd be grateful if you could add an example and I will definitely try it out but all this encryption stuff is a bit scary to me.  Like the IV comment - definitely would be worried that I couldn't decrypt it.  If  you could speak to that with any authority, maybe I could figure out the decryption side :)

Comment: @Missy: It's just a static method returning a `Rijndael` reference. Just use that instead of `new RijndaelManaged`. I'm not going to start answering all the rest of this though - Stack Overflow is designed to be a single issue per post.

Comment: In fact, you should use `Aes.Create()`, not `Rijndael.Create()` (or `new RijndaelManaged()`).  At a BlockSize of 128 they're the same algorithm, but Rijndael allows options that many platforms don't support.  (And Aes.Create() will use new processor instructions to make AES faster when it can)

Answer (score 6):

You are reading exactly one byte at a time. This generates a lot of overhead.

To speed up your processing, start using more bytes at once or call the internal copy function:

```
fsIn.CopyTo(cs);
```

[MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd782932(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 2):

Reading one byte at a time is a terrible idea. Use the built in `Stream.CopyTo` method:

```
fsIn.CopyTo(cs);
```

Note also that deriving an IV from the same material that you derive the key from is bad practice and can lead to security vulnerabilities.  It can even allow an attacker access to the plaintext in some cases.  You should randomly generate an IV for each encryption operation.